# Can Servlets have multi-step interactions?

Tags: java, servlets

Is there any way to start executing java Servlet code (specifically, in Websphere Application Server) (one session, one thread on the Servlet) and then  pause to get more information from the calling client at various points?  I require that the current session, and ongoing Servlet thread, not die until specified, and instead keep waiting (open) for information from the client.

Is this kind of ongoing conversation possible?  Or can the Servlet call to "doPost" only be started - and then the Servlet ignores the client until it finishes?

Comment: Perhaps AJAX is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, I would use an object stored in session to maintain the state needed. You can also modify the session on a servlet by servlet basis if you need certain actions to extend the session timeout beyond the webapp defaults using the following method in the `HttpSession` API:

`public void setMaxInactiveInterval(int interval)` Specifies the time, in seconds, between client requests before the servlet container will invalidate this session. A negative time indicates the session should never timeout.

You just need to establish your logic for your object setting/retrieval from session. Typically something like this:

```
HttpSession session = req.getSession();
MyBeanClass bean;
Object temp = null;

temp = session.getAttribute("myBean");
if(temp !=null) {
    bean = (MyBeanClass) temp;
} else {
    bean = new MyBeanClass();
}

// Logic

session.setAttribute("myBean", bean);
```

Comment: In my case, though, the object is a User Transaction which is assigned by the server on a per-thread basis and retrieved via lookup, not constructed by myself.  So if the thread calling the Servlet finishes and a new servlet call starts (new thread), I will lose access to that original User Transaction simply because the thread has changed and my lookup is different.

Comment: You need to decouple your transaction from the servlet. The user action invokes the servlet, the servlet invokes your transaction object and it gets stored in session. If the user makes another query to the servlet and the transaction object has already been established (it's stored in the session), it is retrieved from session and continued.

Answer (score 1):

I have not done this with directly, but the underlying support is *somewhat* related to [Jetty's continuation model](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Continuations) and [Servlet 3.0 Suspend/Resume support](http://blogs.webtide.com/gregw/entry/patterns_for_servlet_3_0).

Web frameworks that work like the post description (actually, they are resumed across different connections) are sometimes called *[Continuation-Based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) frameworks*. I am unsure of any such frameworks in Java (as the Java language is not conducive to such models) but there are two rather well known examples of the general principle:

1. [Seaside](http://www.seaside.st/) (for Smalltalk) and;
2. [Lift](http://liftweb.net/) (for Scala).

Hope this was somewhat useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can save/update your session state between requests and when the next request comes, you can restore and continue whatever you were doing.